# hypergeometric function and its asymptotic expansion near z=1

Tags: hypergeometric-function

my dear fellows,

I have a question to make. Given the hypergeometric function $_{2}F_{1}[a,b,c,z]$ in the interval $z \in (1, \infty)$. What is the proper asymptotic expansion of the aforesaid function near $z=1$, when one is approaching from $z>1$.

Any help that anyone can kindly provide will be much appreciated.

M.

Comment: which $a,b,c$ are you considering ? or what is the relation among them?

Comment: Hello, I am considering the case where c=a+b. I am trying to find the asymptotic form of the hypergeometric near z=1 but for z \in (1, +\infty). Any ideas?

Comment: did you take a look [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/02/) ?

Comment: Hi G Cab, I looked there but still it does not have an asymptotic expansion at $z=1$ when $z \geq 1$. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Please describe what you tried and what's your level of knowledge of HG. Mine is medium and mainly applicative.

Comment: $c = a + b$ is a logarithmic case, where
$${_2\hspace{-1px}F_1}(a, b; a + b; z) \sim
-\frac {\Gamma(a + b)} {\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)} \ln(1 - z),
\quad z \to 1^-.$$
The values for $z > 1$ will depend on how you choose the analytic continuation. You can define it in such a way that the leading term is the same as above for $z \to 1^+$.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for the help. M.